# Focus on button instead on input field

Tags: jquery, html, material-design

I have an input field and a close button.
When page loads it focus on the input text field (in `ready`) but the same focus command `$("#param_pattern_value").focus();` in other function (when clicking on `tab`) focus on the close button instead on the text input field.

HTML:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="layout-column layout-gt-xs-row layout-align-start-center layout-margin">
<div tabindex="-1" class="classic-text-input mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label flex">
    <input tabindex="0" class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="param_pattern_value"  value="enter text">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="param_pattern_value">
        <span>enter 1</span>
    </label>  

    <button tabindex="0" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button  mdl-button--icon mdl-button--accent margin-left clear_icon_in_input">
        <i class="material-icons mdl-textfield__label__icon">close</i>
    </button>

</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
     $('#param_pattern_value').focus()
});

$("body").keydown(function(e){
        var TAB     = 9;
        var key = e.which;

        if (key == TAB ){
                    $("#param_pattern_value").focus();
        }
    });
```

[LINK TO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wrKac/268/)

I have tried many variations but always after clicking on `tab` it focused on the close button.

Note that on my site, the close button is an "X" icon which placed inside the input field (code looks the same).

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set focus on the `#param_pattern_value` input field whenever a <kbd>TAB</kbd> key occurs, you could add a [**`.preventDefault()`**](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
$("body").keydown(function(e){
    var TAB = 9;
    var key = e.which;

    if (key == TAB ){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#param_pattern_value").focus();
    }
});
```

Please notice, that the `$("#param_pattern_value").focus()` actually does work in your `keydown` code, but your handler fires just before the *default*  `keydown` handler.
You can simply test that using `keyup` instead, or [checking output in console](http://jsfiddle.net/wrKac/270/).

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wrKac/269/)

---

If you simply don't want the <kbd>X</kbd> button to be focused, set `tabindex="-1"` attribute on the button.

Comment: Thank you!! it solved the problem. good point for other similar issues. I need the focus on this button so I'll leave the tabindex="0".